# how to run java project using batch file

Tags: java, batch-file

I have written java project which contains only one class.

I want to run it on another pc's using batch file.

Please advise me how to do this. My class contains parameters for running.

I organize them in such way:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter value1: ");
value1 = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());
```

Path to my java is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin`
My project is in eclipse workspace.

I need to add than I want to see in cmd output "Enter value1: " and have possibility to set this value during execution.

Comment: copy class file to the other PC's folder
cd to the folder
than run 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin\java <Class Name>

Answer (score 3):

You need to write a batch file as mentioned here:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -cp "path of your class files" nameofyourclass
```

Answer (score 1):

The steps to run a Java file are pretty easy:

-) javac NameOfClass.java

-) java -cp . NameOfClass

So the only thing you have to put in the Batch file are these 2 commands.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to compile your code into a Jar file:

Then go to Notepad and Type

```
@echo off
java -jar Myjarfile.jar parameter
```

Save the file as anyfilename.bat in the same location as the Jar File.

Open CMD and Navigate to the Location of your .bat and .jar

execute like this:

```
mybatfile.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use Eclipse (or Idea IntelliJ), you can see the command line used by your IDE in order to make your program run.

For instance, this is my command line. After my "very-long" classpath, you can see the name of the class you want to run ("Main" for me).

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\java" 
   -Didea.launcher.port=7534
  "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12.0.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
  -classpath "C:\Pro[...snip...]12.0.4\lib\idea_rt.jar" 
  com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain Main
```

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin"
javac classname.java
java classname
pause
```

Answer (score -1):

**Step-1:** Create a Java Class and write a below code and save as Math.java in Notepad or using Eclipse IDE.

```
public class Math 
{
public static void addition(){
int a = 20;
int b = 10;
System.out.println(a+b);
}
public static void subtraction(){
int a = 20;
int b = 10;
System.out.println(a-b);
}
public static void division(){          
int a = 20;
int b = 10;     
System.out.println(a/b);
}   
public static void multiplication(){        
int a = 20;
int b = 10;
System.out.println(a*b);
}   
public static void main( String[] args )
{
System.out.println( "Lets Do the Math " );         
Math objectMath = new Math();       
objectMath.addition();
objectMath.subtraction();
objectMath.division();
objectMath.multiplication();      
}
}
```

**Step-2:** Convert the file to executable jar file using Eclipse save as Math.Jar

**Step-3:** Create a bat file in Notepad Or Notepad++ and save as Math.bat

```
@echo off
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -cp "Path of XYZ.Java File" XYZ
java -jar Math.jar parameter
echo Successfully Compiled
pause
```

**Step-4:** Double click the .bat file it should work.

Note: Make sure that bat file java file and jar file all in same when you try.

**Output**
Lets Do the Math
30
10
2
200
Successfully Compiled
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: What is all this? You have two `java` commands in the batch file; *no* `javac`  commands; you are printing 'successfully compiled' after *executing* the JAR file; you have no steps for *creating* the JAR file; you're using `java -jar` but no manifest;  you have an unexplained XYZ in the batch file; your code bears no resemblance to the OP's; ...